# What are resonable expiration dates for JWT token and refresh token?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm wondering what are reasonable value for JWT token and refresh tokens?  I've read that the token should have a short expiration, on the order of 10-15 minutes.  But that the refresh token can be as long as 7 days?  What makes it so secure that it can be valid for so long?

Answer (score 0):

The refresh token is a very sensitive token that you should properly secure, as if the hacker gets hold of it, he can use it for quite some time to create new access tokens.

So, yes you need to take care in the client application and store it in a secure way. Perhaps encrypted?

Many authorization providers today supports one-time refresh tokens, meaning that you can only use a refresh token once and when you use it, you get a new refresh token back. If someone would use the token twice, like you and the hacker. Then your are blocked from getting the token.

see https://leastprivilege.com/2020/01/21/hardening-refresh-tokens/